# Добавление информации в базу используя Ajax и модальные окна asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net, mvc

Здравствуйте, 
Нужно добавить данные в базу с модального окна без перезагрузки основной страницы.

код основной страницы

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.DropDownList("ContractId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <a class="btn btn-info center-block compItem" href='@Url.Action("Create","BuyContracts")'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Добивить</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>  
}
<div id="modDialog" class="modal fade">
    <div id="dialogContent" class="modal-dialog"></div>
</div>

@section scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
       $(".compItem").click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            $.get(this.href, function (data) {
                $('#dialogContent').html(data);
                $('#modDialog').modal('show');
            });
        });
    })
</script>
}
```

Код частичного представления для модального окна

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create","BuyContracts",null,new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" area-hidden="true">X</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContractName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })            
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Модальное окно открывается корректно, но при нажатии кнопки сохранения происходит перезагрузка страницы. Что написать в контроллере, чтобы перезагрузка страницы не происходила?

Answer (score 0):

У вас не хватает обработка javascript ом поста формы внутри модального окна.

```
$('#dialogContent').on('submit', 'form', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // тут необходимо обработать форму аяксом
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужно обновить часть страницы после закрытия модального окна, то можете воспользоваться следующим методом. Мне в своё время очень помог вот такой скрипт:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $(document).on("click", "a[data-modal]", function (e) {
        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
            $('#myModal').modal({
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');

            bindForm(this);
        });
        return false;
    }); 
});

function bindForm(dialog) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        $('#progress').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#progress').hide();  
                    $('#target').load('/Genre/PostFilter #ajaxGrid',
                        {
                            searchString: document.getElementById("searchString").value,
                        });
                } else {
                    $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                    bindForm(this);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

Обратите внимание на $('#target').load, внутри него создаются параметры, которые принимает контроллер, возвращающий частичное представление для обновления части контента. Контроллер должен быть HttpPost. Сам #target - это div, который обновится после выполнения запроса, у меня это была таблица.